# Get user's posts in /users/:id/posts or in /posts/user/:id endpoint in REST API design?

Tags: api, rest

If we search for list of Posts by specific user ID, which of these two endpoints is correct one for getting list of posts by user's ID?

Comment: I think you should use /user/id/posts or /users/id/posts

Answer (score 0):

> 1.2. Collection and Sub-collection Resources
>
> A resource may contain sub-collection resources also.
>
> For example, sub-collection resource “accounts” of a particular
> “customer” can be identified using the URN
> “/customers/{customerId}/accounts” (in a banking domain).
>
> Similarly, a singleton resource “account” inside the sub-collection
> resource “accounts” can be identified as follows:
> “/customers/{customerId}/accounts/{accountId}“.

Then `/users/:id/posts` is the recommended way.

You can read more in: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/